# How to get a map in different languages using Google maps API V2 for android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm building an application using Google Maps Android API v2 and i'm able to get the map:

```
private void initMap() {
        SupportMapFragment mf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = mf.getMap();                      
    }
```

The thing is, my app should support many languages and i was wondering if it's possible to get a map in different languages according to locale?

Comment: Did you get any solution to fetch location details in multiple languages in one call ?

Comment: @Nikhil - this is so old that probably the Problem/Solution are not relevant anymore (not that i can remember what I did :))

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport)

It says that

> The API detects the browser settings of the user and set the language
>   appropriately. It is possible to override the language in the APIs;
>   more information is available in the JavaScript API documentation. Map
>   controls and directions in the Directions Panel have been translated
>   for a subset of languages listed in Supported Languages Spreadsheet.
>   Labels on maps are presented in the preferred language when
>   translations are available.

So, Just **change the locale on the device**. If translations are available, they will be shown automatically.